# How can multiple people grade assignments online so that different graders don't see each others' grades?

Tags: software, grading

this question is related to how you do your double blind marking for assignments, we are looking at the coursework plugin for moodle but are interested in how other other institutions do this. a specialist piece of software? paper? excel spreadsheets?

To clarify this would be two markers not being able to see the grades the other marker has assigned to the student, unless the grade is within a percentage.
This would be passed to a third marker if grades cannot be agreed upon.

Comment: How many student results are you working with?

Comment: Hi, we are working with around 100 students. What about yourselves?

Comment: One lot of 180 the other 160, but I don’t have double marking - just starting to think how I would do it in excel...

Answer (score 1):

This feature is currently not available in Moodle.

Please have a look at the link below.
https://help.blackboard.com/Learn/Instructor/Assignments/Grade_Assignments/Delegated_Grading

Trust this matches your requirement